# Website is not loading the script, CSS, or Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Let me start out by saying that I have very little experience with HTML, javascript and overall website creation and hosting, so sorry in advance if the information I am providing is lacking.
I am trying to make a website by using a 3d object from three.js, however, nothing is loading in the 'live server' (when I upload the entire website to Cpanel), however, when I use visual studio code to run it through my local server (through the command npm run dev) the website is showing as intended. I have screenshotted the pages:

[correct page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBgB.png)

[incorrect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4FqH.png)

When I open the element inspect on the broken page, I get the following error through the console:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a
> MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for
> module scripts per HTML spec.

and

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

i have the following code in my script.js:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js'
import { OrbitControls } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { HemisphereLight, Sphere, SRGB8_ALPHA8_ASTC_12x12_Format, sRGBEncoding, Texture, TextureEncoding } from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js'
import gsap from '../node_modules/gsap/all.js'

var gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
let tl = gsap.timeline()
var diamond = null
```

I am also using this to call the script in the index.html, however, I am uncertain if this is the correct way of calling the script.

```
  <script type=module src="script.js"></script>
```

How would I be able to fix this? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Understand that the browser import functionality is very different than that of Node, or development with a bundler like Webpack. In browser imports, scripts have to be of type `module` (thus causing the cannot use import statement out of module error) `<script type="module" ...` (with the quotes!). You also need to reference an import file starting with `./`, `../`, or `/` (which you already are doing). Finally, you may only import JavaScript files, not CSS.

You have two options:

1. Use a bundler like Webpack to compile your files into a single one (and remove the import statements)
2. (preferred) Remove `import './style.css'` and add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />` in your HTML `<head>`